# Get every row of a tiberius select query, in a vector Rust: error with lifetimes

Tags: rust, lifetime

I connect to a mssql database with tiberius and i get all the data i need into a struct and every struct into a vec, i would like my function to return my vec but i can't understand this borrow problem

> cannot return value referencing local variable `row`
> returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
>
> mod.rs(32, 15): `row` is borrowed here

this is my function

```
use tiberius::{Client, Config, AuthMethod, Query, Row};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio_util::compat::TokioAsyncWriteCompatExt;
pub mod structures;
use structures::*;

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn get_fornitori() -> anyhow::Result<Vec<Fornitori<'static>>> {
    let mut config = Config::new();

    config.host("foo");
    config.port(1433);
    config.authentication(AuthMethod::sql_server("foo", "bar"));
    config.database("foo");
    config.trust_cert(); // on production, it is not a good idea to do this

    let tcp = TcpStream::connect(config.get_addr()).await?;
    tcp.set_nodelay(true)?;

    let mut client = Client::connect(config, tcp.compat_write()).await?;
    let params = vec![String::from("*")];
    let mut select = Query::new("SELECT TOP 3 * FROM foo");
    
    for param in params.into_iter() {
        select.bind(param);
    }
    
    let mut _res = select.query(&mut client).await?;
    let row: Vec<Vec<Row>> = _res.into_results().await?;

    let mut result_vec: Vec<Fornitori> = vec![];
    for i in &row[0] {
        let id_forn: Option<i32> = i.get(0);
        let nome_forn: Option<&str> = i.get(1);
        let pagamento_forn: Option<&str> = i.get(4);
        let forn = Fornitori {
            f_id: id_forn,
            fornitore: nome_forn,
            tipo_pagamento: pagamento_forn,
        };
        result_vec.push(forn);
    }
    println!("rvec: {:#?}", result_vec);

    Ok(result_vec)
}
```

I get the error here:

> Ok(result_vec)

i have the Fornitori struct in another file

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Fornitori<'a> {
    pub f_id: Option<i32>,
    pub fornitore: Option<&'a str>,
    pub tipo_pagamento: Option<&'a str>,
}
```

I have replaced real values with "foo" and "bar".

Comment: Problem seems clear? Your `Fornitori` *borrows* data (strings) which are owned by (the misnamed) `row`, which is owned by the function. So when the function ends `row` is dropped, the strings are destroyed, and your `Fornitori` is left with a dangling pointer. `Fornitori` should contain `Option<String>` and the items should be *moved* from the row to the result. Or if there are cases where a borrow makes sense, `Cow<'a, str>` where in this case `'a` would be `'static`, and the two fields would contain a `Cow::Owned`.

Comment: Also you seem to be making a single query which returns a single resultset, looking at tiberius's documentation you should probably use `into_first_results`, you don't need a double vector of rows. Though collecting to a results vec at all seems unnecessary, why not call `into_row_stream` and lazy-fetch the rows directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're creating new `Fornitori` items it should probably own it's fields:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Fornitori {
    pub f_id: Option<i32>,
    pub fornitore: Option<String>,
    pub tipo_pagamento: Option<String>,
}
```

You can simply create new stings from the string slices you get by mapping with `ToString::to_string`:

```rust
    for i in &row[0] {
        let f_id = i.get(0);
        let fornitore = i.get(1).map(|f: &str| f.to_string());
        let tipo_pagamento = i.get(4).map(|t: &str| t.to_string());
        let forn = Fornitori {
            f_id,
            fornitore,
            tipo_pagamento,
        };
        result_vec.push(forn);
    }
```

Comment: Looking at [`tiberius::FromSql`](https://docs.rs/tiberius/latest/tiberius/trait.FromSql.html) it doesn't look like the explicit conversion / map is necessary, its table states that string sql types will convert to and from either `String` or `&str`. So just changing the fields should suffice.

Comment: While it's listed in that table I don't see `String` in the implementations on foreign types below, since I can't test it I'll leave it in for now.

Comment: Thank you that's a nice idea but i get an error on "i.get(1).map(ToString::to_string);" and "i.get(4).map(ToString::to_string);" both errors are here "get" both errors are:             "` type annotations needed multiple `impl`s satisfying `&_: tiberius::FromSql<'_>` found in the `tiberius` crate:"                                                                             "consider specifying the type arguments in the function call: `::<'a, R, I>

Comment: Try removing the `.map(…)` all together like Masklinn suggests, if that doesn't work see my edit.